# Center fixed marker in android v2 mapview

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-activity

I want to set fixed marker in the center point of `mapview` while dragging map.It has been done at android Map V1 google `mapview`. But now it's deprecated.Now my question is, is it possible in android Map V2 google `mapview` ?(I have tried.but map doesn't show)

Comment: have you try to use moveCamera() or animateCamera() ?

Comment: yeah.My problem is marker are also moving while dragging map

Comment: I want to set fixed marker at the center of mapView while dragging map

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I'm betting you used `getMapCenter()` which, as per Google Maps for Android v2, no longer available to use. But no worries, just use this:

```
GoogleMap.getCameraPosition().target
```

It will return a `LatLng` object which basically represents the center of the map. You can then use it to reposition the marker to the center every time there's a drag event by assigning an `OnCameraChangedListener` to your `GoogleMap`.

```
yourGMapInstance.setOnCameraChangeListener(new OnCameraChangedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCameraChange (CameraPosition position) {

        // Get the center of the Map.
        LatLng centerOfMap = yourGMapInstance.getCameraPosition().target;

        // Update your Marker's position to the center of the Map.
        yourMarkerInstance.setPosition(centerOfMap);
    }
});
```

There. I hope this helped!

Comment: Now, GoogleMap.OnCameraChangeListener() is deprecated. Instead of that use  following method GoogleMap.OnCameraMoveStartedListener, GoogleMap.OnCameraMoveListener, GoogleMap.OnCameraIdleListener

Answer (score 14):

So you want something like a cross-hairs on the center of map, right?

I have not used MapView. But I have used Map Fragment, and the way i implement a fix marker on the map is use a ImageView, So you will end up with something like below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragment1"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:src="@drawable/cross_hairs" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

You could swap the MapFragment with MapView.

Placing the marker on the map will be inefficient, since you will need to keep updating the marker when the user pans the map.

Hope it helps!

Comment: A better approach. Much appreciated.

Comment: how to give a shadow to the imageview in this case, the shadow must fall on map

Answer (score 2):

Notice that `setOnCameraChangeListener()` has been deprecated, so you can use the new camera listeners (`OnCameraIdleListener`, `OnCameraMoveListener`,  `OnCameraMoveStartedListener`, `OnCameraMoveCanceledListener`), for example:

```
map.setOnCameraMoveListener(new GoogleMap.OnCameraMoveListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCameraMove() {
        // Get the center of the map
        LatLng center = map.getCameraPosition().target;
        ......
    }
});
```

for more information, read this: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/events

Answer (score 0):

Simply goto the XML File: Add Image View in map fragment and set the gravity to `center`. Then goto the Java File and add the following java code into your onMayReady Function:

```
 <fragment
                android:id="@+id/map"
                android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/bottom_navigation"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/linearLayout2" />
    
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView_map_marker"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="17dp"
                android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:tooltipText="Select Location"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_baseline_location_red" />


    mMap.setOnCameraMoveListener(new GoogleMap.OnCameraMoveListener() {
                 @Override
                 public void onCameraMove() {
                     mMap.clear();
                     binding.imageViewMapMarker.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        
                 }
             });
        
             mMap.setOnCameraIdleListener(new GoogleMap.OnCameraIdleListener() {
                 @Override
                 public void onCameraIdle() {
                     binding.imageViewMapMarker.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                     selectedLatitude=mMap.getCameraPosition().target.latitude;
                     selectedLongitude=mMap.getCameraPosition().target.longitude;
                     MarkerOptions marker = new MarkerOptions().position(mMap.getCameraPosition().target).title("")
                             .icon(bitmapDescriptorFromVector(getApplicationContext(), R.drawable.ic_baseline_location_red));
                     mMap.addMarker(marker);
        
                 }
             });
```

[image]